# What does this representation of organic aromatic compounds mean?

Tags: organic-chemistry

I saw this structure in some problem. What does this mean? How to express this in form of a simple structure

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the cyclooctatetraene dianion. One way to get to it is to start with cyclooctatriene and remove one hydrogen ion each from the two $\ce{- CH2 -}$ groups. This is related to the cyclopentadienyl anion, the more common aromatic anion.

[image]
Image source: https://www.masterorganicchemistry.com/2017/05/17/frost-circles/

Answer (score 2):

It represents a dianion structure that is, delocalisation of 2 negative charges around the ring. It's like extracting two $\ce{H+}$ from the structure of cyclooctatriene or adding two electrons to the structure of cyclooctatetraene.

That is how we represent the net resonance hybrid structure which is a combination of all the canonical structures we can make(which is what I assume you mean by 'simple' structures).

[image]